# Recursive calls for Binary Tree Destructor

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree, destructor

from my understanding, this code for binary search tree destructor works:

```
~tree(){

    remove(root);
}

void remove(node* root) 
{
    if (root == NULL) return;
    remove(root->left);
    remove(root->right);
    delete root;
}
```

However, I would like to know if the following call for destructor works?

```
~node(){
    delete left;
    delete right;
}

~tree(){
    delete root;
}
```

My understanding is that deleting the root would automatically call the child nodes and delete them as well. Is that a correct assumption? **If it is indeed correct, what is a simple approach to verify that the destructor is working?**

**{{This part of the post has been added later}}**

I am using the second method here. Going by the output expression verification, the code below does not seem to be working, because I am getting a single delete output (which seemingly is for the root node)

```
struct node{

    ~node(){
     delete left;
     delete right;
     }  
};

class tree {
     node* root;

public:

     tree(){
         root=NULL;
     }

     ~tree(){
         cout<<"Deleting: "<<endl;
         delete root;
      }

      void insert (int x){};
}

int main(){

      A.insert(12);A.insert(13);A.insert(10);

      return 0;
}
```

Here is the output I am getting:

```
 Deleting:
```

Ideally, there should be 3 such expressions but I am getting only 1.

Comment: You should be careful of making cycles in your tree.  If you have a tree that points back to itself, this code (both versions) can explode.

Comment: If you use smart pointers instead of regular ones, your destructors become empty and you don't need `remove`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on smart pointers please? And is there a simple approach to test if the destructor is working?

Comment: @ n.m, Is there ant way I can verify that the destructor is working? My understanding is that if I include the "cout" statement in the destructor, it would repeat for every element of in the tree, and that would kind of verify that the destructor is working. Is that correct?

Comment: This `{margin}` is too small, but basically you use `std:unique_ptr<node> left, right;` instead of `node *left, *right;` and just forget about `delete`.

Comment: Yes that would be strong evidence for the destructor working. Of course you can rarely verify that something works. You can only verify that something does *not* work. I.e. verification can show that you have bugs, it cannot show that you have *no* bugs.

Comment: Please check the edit I have made in the original post. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will work provided that leaf nodes have left and right equal to nullptr.

Acccording to the C++ Standard (5.3.5 Delete)

> 6 If the value of the operand of the delete-expression **is not a null
>   pointer value**, the delete-expression **will invoke the destructor**
>   (if any) for the object or the elements of the array being deleted. In
>   the case of an array, the elements will be destroyed in order of
>   decreasing address (that is, in reverse order of the completion of
>   their constructor; see 12.6.2).

So the destructor of a node will be called only in case when the node is not a null pointer value.

If you want to check that the destructor is indeed working then simply insert an output statement in the body of the destructor.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    node *next;
    int x;
    ~node()
    {
        std::cout << "inside node: " << x << std::endl;
        delete next;
    }
};

void push_front( node **tree, int x )
{
    node *n = new node;
    n->x = x;
    n->next = *tree;

    *tree = n;
}

void clear( node **tree )
{
    delete *tree;
    *tree = nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    node *tree = nullptr;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) push_front( &tree, i );

    clear( &tree );
}
```

The output is

```
Compiled with /EHsc /nologo /W4
main.cpp

Compilation successful!

Total compilation time: 187ms

inside node: 9

inside node: 8

inside node: 7

inside node: 6

inside node: 5

inside node: 4

inside node: 3

inside node: 2

inside node: 1

inside node: 0

Total execution time: 734ms
```

Comment: This should always be the case, sind otherwise they were not leaf nodes.

Comment: @Codor Yes it is the condition of stopping the recursion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please just help me with verifying that the destructor is working? My understanding is that if I include the "cout" statement in the destructor, it would repeat for every element of in the tree, and that would kind of verify that the destructor is working. Is that correct?

Comment: And by the way, I have tried doing that. Only a single output expression is shown for the head node. Is that a sign things are wrong?

Comment: Please check the edit I have made in the original post. Thanks

Comment: @Learner You have to output the message in the destructor of node.

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not work, as the destructor would permit calling `delete` on `NULL` pointers.